# Dar color a las salidas de python 3

Tags: python-3.x

Tengo el siguiente print:

print("\033[4;35m"+"Texto en negrita y subrayado de color morado")

Segun vi en una pagina de internet, este servia para dar color a esa salida, pero en realidad cuando ejecuto ese script, en vez de imprimirme esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me imprime esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Esos caracteres de escape sigun un estándar llamado ANSI que tu terminal debe cumplir para que funcione. La terminal de Windows no lo cumple. Te recomiendo echar un vistazo a [colorama](https://pypi.org/project/colorama/)

Comment: Si funciona el modulo, pero solo en los print, no en los input ( se muestra como la imagen numero 2 de la pregunta, pero esta vez con el modulo colorama ). ¿Porque pasa esto?

Comment: Parece un bug de colorama relacionado con Python 3.7. Tiene [una issue abierta](https://github.com/tartley/colorama/issues/234), quizás lo arreglen. Supongo que entretanto siempre puedes usar `print("prompt con colores", end="")` seguido de `result = input()`

Comment: ¿Sabes que modulo (o cualquier otra técnica) me sirve para cambiar la fuente y el tamaño de las cadenas en python 3?

Comment: En una terminal no puedes cambiar fuente ni tamaño a nivel de caracter o línea, sólo puedes hacerlo para la terminal completa, y no desde python (o desde otro lenguaje), sino mediante las opciones de configuración de la terminal. Para tener texto con estilos, necesitas usar algún framework para interfaces gráficas de usuario (como tkinter que viene con python). En general son muy complejos. Mucho más que una terminal. Quizás lo más simple sería que generases la salida en HTML y luego la mostraras en un navegador.